# Partitioning feature causes the crash error in GridDB (FDW)

Tags: griddb

Regarding to the table partitioning feature, It causes the crash error by the following scenario:

```
create table itrtest (a int, b text) partition by list (a);
create foreign table remp1 (a int, b text) server griddb_svr options (table_name 'locp1');
alter table itrtest attach partition remp1 for values in (1);
insert into itrtest values (1, 'foo');
```

Server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

```
connection to server was lost
```

Does GridDB FDW support the table partitioning feature? Could you please fix this issue?